# Line editing in dash

Tags: command-line, dash-shell

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) or [mksh](/questions/tagged/mksh) it is possible to move around the typed line word by word, using [shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) such as <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

That doesn't work in [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) or [dash](/questions/tagged/dash). As far as I understand from googling, this has something to do with readline support, however nowhere I've seen it mention how to enable support for dash.

That's the core of my question: **How to enable line navigation for dash**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is:

## You don't.

`dash` is a direct descendent of the Almquist Shell (`ash`). `ash` never featured line editing support, and neither does `dash`. Busybox `ash` does, so if you must an `ash` variant for some reason *and* have line editing, etc., use Busybox `ash`. Nobody's going to bother with adding readline support, since `dash`'s primary use is for running shell scripts.

Unless, of course, you're willing to code support for readline in `dash`, and maintain such a patch yourself...

The long answer is:

## Compile with `libedit`

If you look at [`dash`'s manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dash.1.html):

```
-V vi           Enable the built-in vi(1) command line editor
                (disables -E if it has been set).

-E emacs        Enable the built-in emacs(1) command line editor
                (disables -V if it has been set).
```

These only work if `dash` was compiled with `--with-libedit`. It isn't, neither in [Ubuntu](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/dash/wily/view/head:/debian/rules#L49), nor, [apparently, in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=561663).

You can build it thus:

```
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git
cd dash 
./autogen.sh 
./configure --with-libedit 
make
```

Then run:

```
src/dash -E
```

You should be able to use the arrow keys to edit the current command.

Answer (score 6):

If you definitely want `dash` plus command-line editing and history, you can use [`rlwrap`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/rlwrap):

```
rlwrap dash
```

Suggestion:

```
rlwrap -cmD2 dash
```

To use `rlwrap`, you'll have to:

```
sudo apt-get install rlwrap
```