# vi editing mode in dash ( /bin/sh )

Tags: command-line, dash-shell

**TL;DR** : default shell man page says there's vi editing mode, but `set -o vi` doesn't actually enable it

In many shells, including `dash` the POSIX standard dictates that `set -o vi` will enable vi editing mode, in which user of *interactive* shell can navigate line using vi-style of shortcuts. In `dash` ( Ubuntu's default shell symlinked to `/bin/sh` ) this doesn't work, even though man page specifies that this feature is available.

Example :

```
$ dash
$ set -o vi
$ hello wolrd^[I
```

What was supposed to happen there is that with <kbd>Esc</kbd> , <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> shortcut the cursor should have jumped to the beginning of the line. As you can see, I get a control character as output instead. I've asked a few users to test this in AskUbuntu Chat, and they confirmed the same behavior.

Note, that this is not related to terminal emulator - I tested it in 3 different ones: xterm, gnome-terminal, and terminator. I've tested this with other shells, `bash`, `mksh` and `ksh93` - all work properly as expected, so this is `dash`-only issue.

Comment: Turn on vi mode in dash with set -oV

Comment: Serg, Ubuntu's default `dash` does not come with any Readline (or similar) library support leading to this behavior.

Comment: @chaskes that didn't work

Comment: @heemayl  I do know that.  But `ksh` also doesn't have readline support, yet vi mode works there.  If that's the case, then why `man dash` doesn't reflect this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious about this so I downloaded a source code tarball from the [upstream DASH downloads](http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/files/) and extracted the source files. I checked for a README file which should provide information on the program and its build options, but there wasn’t any, so I ran `./configure  --help` and its output includes:

```
Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-libedit          Compile with libedit support
```

So, it looks like the [libedit](http://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/NetBSD/NetBSD-current/src/lib/libedit) library is used to provide line editing capabilities but this is not the default when building the source.  I also found this response to a mailing list message on [set -o vi](https://www.mail-archive.com/dash@vger.kernel.org/msg00623.html) not working:

> I think this requires dash to be built with libedit support to work.

I checked what libraries were linked to the `dash` executable on my Ubuntu server and noted `libedit` wasn’t included:

```
$ ldd /bin/dash
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcfbd6000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f013a0b7000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f013a475000)
```

I imagine that when the Debian package maintainers are building the `dash` package, they omit this optional configuration as they would not want `sh` to have external dependencies on other libraries. They could probably link the library statically but the main reason for using `dash` as `sh` is to keep the shell as small and fast as possible so that the start-up scripts run quickly.

**Edit**: I just [searched for “libedit dash”](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=libedit+dash&t=ffsb&ia=qa&iax=1) and the top result was a [very similar question on this site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704688/line-editing-in-dash) which was well answered by muru.

#### Building Dash with line editing support

For those who might be interested, these are are steps required to build from source.

1. Download the most recent source tarball:

   ```
   wget http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/files/dash-0.5.9.tar.gz
   wget http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/files/dash-0.5.9.tar.gz.sha256sum
   ```
2. Verify the authenticity of the tarball:

   ```
   sha256sum -c <( awk '/dash/{ print $1 "  "  $3}' dash-0.5.9.tar.gz.sha256sum )
   gpg --verify --auto-key-retrieve dash-0.5.9.tar.gz.sha256sum
   ```
3. Extract the source files and change into the source directory:

   ```
   tar -xf dash-0.5.9.tar.gz
   cd dash-0.5.9
   ```
4. Run `./configure --with-libedit` to create the Make files. However, this will fail quietly unless the development version of the `libedit` library is installed. It would be better if the configure script complained more verbosely as it wasn’t obvious that it was failing to find the required files.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libedit-dev
   ./configure --with-libedit
   ```
5. Build the program and (optionally) install it into `/usr/local/bin`:

   ```
   make
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: That same question that was answered by muru was asked by me :)

Comment: That's not exactly the case of bad memory here. I discovered vi editing mode only a few days ago. Since i use vim a lot now, i had idea that this might be used in dash. Back when i asked that question vi and emacs editing modes didn't concern me, so i didn't notice  that part of muru's answer.  It's a bit disappointing because POSIX standard requires having vi editing mode, so Debian and Ubuntu devs basically don't match up to POSIX when they compile dash without libedit. Sad but i guess we just have to deal with it

Comment: @Serg Ah. That makes sense. Despite being a Vim user,I still haven't made up my mind whether I prefer vi or emac mode for line editing. FWIW, I noticed that tcsh had nicer support for vi-mode than Bash's Readline. BTW, I've built dash with `libedit` and the line editing works fine. I still couldn't see myself using it as my regular shell since it lacks tab completion as it isn't specified by POSIX.

Comment: I don't intend to regularly use dash as interactive shell as well, but it is nice to have it handy when I mess up my rc files for either bash or mksh ( which is what I regularly use ).   Yeah, Tab completion is also something that would be nice to have, but I could leave without it. Inability to edit commands is what drives me up the wall

Comment: @Serg It took me a lot longer than I intended to build the source code so I've edited my answer to include those steps. Since dash is so small, the build is very fast - as long as you have the necessary library development files.