# Why the login-shell is bash, but the /bin/sh is the link of dash?

Tags: bash, unity-dash

Generally，the value of environment variable `SHELL`  is /bin/bash, it means normal shell  environment is Bash，However，the /bin/sh is the link of Dash, what is the Dash effect？

Another question: Although our shell environment is bash, why sometimes it will go wrong because of dash？

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Maybe this will help - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh , which states "*The major reason to switch the default shell was efficiency. bash is an excellent full-featured shell appropriate for interactive use; indeed, it is still the default login shell. However, it is rather large and slow to start up and operate by comparison with dash*"

Answer (score 2):

### General comment about `sh`

The shell `sh` is a symbolic link to `dash`, which is a shell with a very light foot-print. It means that it can [work quickly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976485/what-is-the-point-of-sh-being-linked-to-dash) and will not use much memory. But the built-in commands are few, simple and have different syntax compared to more advanced shells (for example `bash`).

Both shells (`sh` and `bash`) are useful but for different purposes.

### How to make a shellscript run by `bash`

If you run a text file with commands, a shellscript, you can force it to run by a certain shell. Otherwise it may default to a shell, that does does not work as intended, for example because some built-in command does not exist or the syntax for a built-in command is different.

So in order to make a shellscript run with `bash`, you can force it

- by calling it from `bash`

  ```
  bash shellscriptname
  ```
- by writing a line at the top of the file, a first line with the content

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ```

  This is called 'shebang'. The shebang can point to other shells too, for example `sh` or `csh` but also other programs, for example `python` or `bc`. If you make the shellscript file executable

  ```
  chmod +x shellscriptname
  ```

  you can run it with the following command

  ```
  ./shellscriptname                        # when in the current directory
  path-to-the-script-file/shellscriptname  # when somewhere else
  shellscriptname                          # when in a directory in PATH
  ```

  and it will be executed by the shell or other program in the shebang.

Answer (score 2):

They main point is that `bash` is meant for interactive use, `dash` is used for system scripts.

`bash` comes with whole lot of features, among which is line editing. You have specific shortcuts to delete a word, jump to beginning of line, etc. This is convenient for writing commands interactively. However that comes at a price of performance and boot up times.

`dash` on the other hand is meant for writing system scripts that are [fast and portable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976485/what-is-the-point-of-sh-being-linked-to-dash), thus helping keep the boot times short, and on Ubuntu it is [compiled without line editing](https://askubuntu.com/q/826754/295286), even without `vi` editing mode. Thus, it has less overhead. `bash` is capable of running exactly same scripts `/bin/dash` runs ( if they are written with portable syntax, of course ), but `dash` is just faster at doing these same things.

Note, of course, that users are free to [change their login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422876/85039) via `chsh` command, and you don't have to stick with `bash` if that's not what you prefer.