# fc built in missing from dash ( i.e.,dash shell history doesn't work )?

Tags: command-line, dash-shell

In `dash` manual, under `Builtins` section there exists explanation on `fc` built in which controls shell history and re-executes commands from it, `FCEDIT` and `HISTSIZE` also are mentioned there. Yet when I try to execute it `dash` gives command not found error.

```
$ echo one
one
$ fc -l 1
dash: 2: fc: not found
$ fc
dash: 3: fc: not found
```

Question is, why ?  Is it one of the standard and conscious choices that Ubuntu developers made or I may need to enable `fc` somehow ?

I have found [Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=252498) that mentions `fc`, but the patch mentioned there is for i386 and last activity on the report has been in 2008, so nothing regarding Ubuntu so far. And [historically](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/ash/), fc has had fixes and exists in versions for different BSD releases, so there's gotta be something Ubuntu-specific or Debian-specific here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [line number 57-59](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/builtins.def.in#n57) in `src/builtins.def.in` of the dash source code:

```
#ifndef SMALL
histcmd     -u fc
#endif
```

SMALL is defined if `--with-libedit` is *not* set in configure, which is the case for our dash/sh. I guess it's about optimzing the memory footprint.

Also Changelog says:

```
2005-10-29  Herbert Xu <herbert@gondor.apana.org.au>
[...]
* Disable histcmd completely when SMALL is defined.
[...]
```

If not compiling with `--with-libedit` was a deliberate choice or not is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: You're right. Apparently, `--with-libedit` strips out whole lot of features that rely on it. It kinda goes back to my older question https://askubuntu.com/a/704719/295286   Kinda becomes predictable :)

Comment: To put it differently: Poor ubuntu dash is crippled, bound to just serve as /bin/sh. I admit a package with a full version of dash would be nice to have in addition.

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  And frankly, I think it's even more restricted than POSIX `/bin/sh`. I can see advantage in speed for older hardware, but we're kinda in 2018 already, and keeping `/bin/sh` doesn't provide that much speed up. Taking advantage of newer hardware with multicore processors seems to be better.